# Update variable every second during timer execution

Tags: c#

I have a timer that runs for 18 seconds and I was wondering if it is possible to update a variable every 1.5 seconds during the timer count down.

Would it be easier to just have 2 timers one for 18 seconds and another for 1.5 seconds.

Is there any other method that could be easier or better.

Comment: Please, show us your timer function. What timer you are using? If the timer you use has a method where you get the current countdown time in milli seconds, you can use modulo 1500, like if(currentcountdownTimeInMs % 1500 == 0) ...

Answer (score 2):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive"). Then you can do this:

```
long x = 0L;
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5))
    .Take(12) // 18 seconds
    .Subscribe(n =>
    {
        //update variable
        x = n;
    }, () =>
    {
        //Runs when timer ends.
    });
```

It avoids all the mucky timers that you're asking about.

In a nutshell, though, if you want to use timers, then you need only one for the 1.5 second interval - but stop this after 12 times to give you the 18 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, this has really helped.

Comment: I desided to use a timer set to 1.5 seconds because this program is supposed to work on any computer on my university campus and I think the program should just work without needing to install other components.

Comment: If your 18 second requirement needs to be tight you might find that the 1.5 second timer drifts and 12 repetitions always lasts a bit more than 18 seconds.  The time goes off no less than 1.5 seconds so usually longer.  The result is the errors will accumulate 12 times over.  Again, irrelevant if your tolerances are loose or repetitions remain low.

Comment: @DeclanMarks referencing a NuGet package doesn't mean the end user has to install other components. In fact, if you look at the future (.Net Core) the whole framework consists of NuGet packages.

Comment: @rfreytag When using Reactive is it possible to start it from another class.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long Elapsed;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // set interval to 1.5 seconds 1500 (milliseconds)
        timer.Interval = 1500;
        // set tick event withs will be runt every 1.5 seconds  1500 (milliseconds)
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        // start timer
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add 1500 milliseconds to elapsed 1500 = 1.5 seconds
        Elapsed += 1500;
        // check if 18 seconds have elapsed
        // after 12 times it will be true 18000 / 1500 = 12
        if (Elapsed == 18000) 
        {
            // stop the timer if it is
            timer.Stop();
        }
        // update variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am using async/await for that - this helped me with PCL which has not event timers

```
    private async void RunTimerAsync()
    {
           await Timer();
    }

    private async Task Timer()
    {
         while (IsTimerStarted)
         {
               //Your piece of code for each timespan
               //ElapsedTime += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
               await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
         }
   }
```

Comment: Task.Delay uses a Timer internally. Also, you will need to extend your answer to include the 18 seconds ticks as well